# Locally Hölder Continuous Function

Tags: analysis

I want to show that the fuction $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$ is locally Hölder continuous, I used the **mean value theorem**, but does not work. Tools that I need to resolve?.

Also does definitión is:

if $f$ is a function $(f:\Omega\longrightarrow\mathbb{R})$, then $f$ locally Hölder continuous iff there are $M$, $\alpha$ such that for each $k\subseteq \Omega $, $k$ compact
$$|f(x)-f(y)|\leq M|x-y|^\alpha\;\;\;\;\;\;\forall x,y\in k?$$

Thanks for your help, I do not speak good English and I'm new.

Answer (score 1):

The function is locally Hölder continuous because it is $C^1$. In fact it is locally Lipschitz continuous (that is, you can take $\alpha=1$ in each compact set).

Comment: Thank you. To show it, I proceed as follows: if $f:(0,+\infty)\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)=\frac{1}{1+x^2}$, then $f$ is continuos in $[a,b](a>0,b>0)$ and differentiable in $(a,b)$, so mean value theorem is valid and existe $c\in(a,b)$ such that $$|f(b)-f(a)|\leq f'(c)|b-a|$$,  $if \;\;\;\;\;\;M=f'(c)\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;|f(x)-f(y)|\leq M|x-y|\;\;\;\;\;\forall x,y\in[a,b]$$\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;$Is this right?

Comment: Yes, like that is fine.

Comment: Is there another way?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, this is pretty immediate.

Comment: Like this is OK, thanks.